# Замена пустого массива текстом PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, mysql

есть цикл, который выводит данные о пользователях из БД.

```
<?php
$strSQL = "SELECT * 
FROM users WHERE name = 'Admin' ";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
   echo "<p>Имя:".$row['name']."</p>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на странице показался заголовок " Пользователь не найден " если массив ничего не выведет. Т.е. если name Admin не будет, а будет User, тогда он ничего не выведет, т.к. в условии написано, чтобы выводил там, где name = Admin

Comment: Просто совет. Переходите с mysql на mysqli или pdo_mysql. mysql как таковая - устарела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$strSQL = "SELECT * 
FROM users WHERE name = 'Admin' ";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

if(mysql_num_rows($rs) != 0) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
      echo "<p>Имя:".$row['name']."</p>";
   }
} else {
   echo "<p>Пользователь не найден.</p>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Можно убрать фигурные скобки, когда используете в условие одну функцию или одно другое условие:

```
<?php
$strSQL = "SELECT * 
FROM users WHERE name = 'Admin' ";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

if(mysql_num_rows($rs) != 0)
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
      echo "<p>Имя:".$row['name']."</p>";
else
   echo "<p>Пользователь не найден.</p>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_num_rows() должен помочь, если 0, то выводить нужный текст.

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ кодом, пожалуйста.